# confused between gravity, alignparent, aligncomponent,

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android programming, and I try to do a simple app first, but I need to understand how to arrange items with one another. There are xml attributes called gravity, layout_gravity, alignParentLeft, alignComponent, ...

It seems to me that, for instance, gravity="left" and alignParentRight="true" will be contradictory. Am I wrong? What's the difference between these alignment attributes?

Thanks

Comment: What's with the downvotes...My question is too stupid for stack overflow? Where should I post?

Answer (score 2):

Please look at details below :

- **android:gravity** sets the gravity of the content of the View its used
  on.
- **android:layout_gravity** sets the gravity of the View or Layout in
  its parent.
- **android:layout_alignBottom** Makes the bottom edge of this view match
  the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID.
- **android:layout_alignEnd**  Makes the end edge of this view match the
  end edge of the given anchor view ID.
- **android:layout_alignLeft** Makes the left edge of this view match the
  left edge of the given anchor view ID.
- **android:layout_alignParentBottom** If true, makes the bottom edge of
  this view match the bottom edge of the parent.
- **android:layout_alignParentEnd** If true, makes the end edge of this
  view match the end edge of the parent.
- **android:layout_alignParentLeft** If true, makes the left edge of this
  view match the left edge of the parent.
- **android:layout_alignParentRight**  If true, makes the right edge of
  this view match the right edge of the parent.
- **android:layout_alignParentStart**  If true, makes the start edge of
  this view match the start edge of the parent.
- **android:layout_alignParentTop** If true, makes the top edge of this
  view match the top edge of the parent.
- **android:layout_alignRight** Makes the right edge of this view match
  the right edge of the given anchor view ID.
- **android:layout_alignStart** Makes the start edge of this view match
  the start edge of the given anchor view ID.
- **android:layout_alignTop** Makes the top edge of this view match the
  top edge of the given anchor view ID.

For more information on layout parameters check here :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Comment: Ok, so a few questions: Setting layout_gravity to "left" means that the gravity of ALL children of the parents view will be "left" (not only the one where layout_gravity has been set)? If no, what's the difference between layout_gravity="left" and layout_alignParentLeft="true"? What about align_component? What's the difference between the "baseline" and the "bottom"?

Comment: @  kaleidoscop : Sure..!!

Comment: @kaleidoscop setting layout_gravity to "left" means itself will laying on the left of it's parent (Used in LinearLayout).

And layout_alignParentLeft will do the same as layout_gravity="left" but this is used in RelativeLayout

Comment: Ok thanks, I still don't understand why it was useful to define both the gravity class and the layout_align class for doing the same thing

Comment: Dude stay polite, you just copy pasted the developer.android.com webpage, you could have just pointed me to the whole web saying that the answer was lying somewhere... I just don't understand why such different attributes to fill the same function. The whole point is that I want to program properly, using attribute with its purpose.

Comment: @ kaleidoscop : Hahaha..Fairly before asking more and more questions you should try for yourself..!! and you stuck then you can take advice..!!

Answer (score 1):

gravity is applied to view's child view

layout_gravity applied to itself in it's parent view (in linearLayout)

alignParentRight is to align view itself to the right-first (in RelativeLayout)

Linear and Relative layout use different properties.